# R - saving ggplot objects created with map

Tags: r, purrr

Let's say we run the following code:

```
iris %>% 
    group_split(Species) %>% 
    map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+
            geom_point())
```

This will create three separate scatterplots of Sepal Length vs Sepal Width, grouped by species.

But now, let's say I want to save the three files as .png. I want them to be called `setosa.png`, `versicolor.png` and `virginica.png`. How can I do this without leaving the `map` "*loop*"? I know I can save the plots in a list and then invoke a `for` loop to save them, but this is specifically what I want to avoid.

I want to start off like this:

```
iris %>% 
    group_split(Species) %>% 
    map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+
            geom_point()) %>%
    map(ggsave)
```

But this code will fail since I didn't provide the file name. So what's the way to do this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in the same `map` instead of adding another `map` command. You can get the name of the file from the `Species` column extracting the `first` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ggsave(paste0(first(.$Species),'.png'), 
              ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+
            geom_point()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to do it without `purrr`. However, it requires creation of a custom function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
save_plots <- function(df) {
  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(v) {ggsave(filename = paste(df$Species[v], "png", sep="."),
                                         plot = df$plot[v][[1]], device = "png")})
  }


iris %>%
  nest_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(plot = list(ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+
                       geom_point())) %>%
  save_plots()
```